# How to fuzzy match multiple columns (both pairwise and across combinations)

Tags: r, matching

Say I have four columns, I want to fuzzy match these columns in order to figure out which values are present across pairs and across combinations of columns. Pairwise is straightforward (e.g. 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4, 3-4), but I also want to see whether a character is common to 1-2-3, or whether there are values that are present in all 4 columns (for example, "dolor" should appear in all of them). Is there a systematic way to do this in R?

```
col1 <- c("Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit", "sed", "do")

col2 <- c("Lorem", "ipsum", "Dolor", "adipiscing", "elite", "sed", "doo")

col3 <- c("dolore", "adipiscing", "sed", "doo")

col4 <- c("ipsun", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consecteture", "adipiscing", "elit", "sed", "do")
```

The idea would then be to have a dataset which would have four columns corresponding to each of the four vectors above, 16 rows corresponding to the different combinations of columns, and a column for the frequency of words which are common to each combination of columns.

Comment: you said there were columns, and yet they are not in a dataframe  am I missing something?

Comment: I left these as separate columns as I wasn't sure if the setup/analysis worked better like this or as a merged dataset

Comment: I think either is okay. I was confused  because the lengths were all different!